# In OCaml, why is there an auxiliary function in Core's List.find?

Tags: list, ocaml

In Core, `List.find` is defined using an auxiliary function, as follows:

```
let find l ~f =
  let rec find_aux = function
    | []       -> None
    | hd :: tl -> if f hd then Some hd else find_aux tl
  in
  find_aux l
```

But it can be defined directly. For instance:

```
let rec find l ~f =
  match l with
  | []       -> None
  | hd :: tl -> if f hd then Some hd else find tl f
```

Is there any advantage in using an auxiliary function for defining a function such as `List.find`?

Comment: In Haskell the additional inlining opportunities you get by doing this sort of thing are a big deal. I don't know if OCaml is the same. Search terms: static argument transformation, worker-wrapper transformation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't change much because both functions are tail-recursive, but still, the answer to your question is:

calling `find` requires passing two arguments. Calling `find_aux` requires passing one argument. Passing arguments is not free: they take up space on the stack, limiting the maximum recursion depth if the function is not tail-recursive, and they take time to set up.

It is a trade-off: in Core's version, a closure must be allocated to bind the name `f` to its (locally) permanent value. If the list is short, allocating the closure can be more expensive than passing a few additional arguments (esp. since the function is tail-recursive).

Basically, you shouldn't worry about it. It is probably unnecessary in this case, and even when it is not unnecessary, it does not make a big difference.